# grep returns lines with no matching text and does not provide line number with -n flag

Tags: linux, grep

I have a large csv file with over 1 million rows.  I am getting some strange hexadecimal looking output in some rows that don't match the rest of the data.  I wanted to use grep to quickly find the specific rows in the original text (csv) file.

I searched for the hexadecimal looking values with:

```
grep -n 7CEC119CA8D46F42DC3DB4A971357E7D large_csv.txt
```

The output is one line, but does not contain the usual line-number followed by a ':', and does not highlight any matches (as there are none).
I can't show the output, as there is identifiable information in it, but the results do not contain `7CEC119CA8D46F42DC3DB4A971357E7D`, or anything close.  I tried hexadecimal converters, but nothing matches at all in the returned line or the lines above `-A` or below `-B`.

If I change a single letter or digit in `7CEC119CA8D46F42DC3DB4A971357E7D` I don't get a match and no output is returned as expected.
However, if I remove any number of characters or digits from `7CEC119CA8D46F42DC3DB4A971357E7D` (less than the length of course) I get the same output as above with nothing highlighted and no line-number.

When I do pick something unique from the match line and re-run `grep -n` with that string, the output is the same line except this time the match is highlighted and the line-number is shown.

What is grep matching?

Comment: Is it possible that binary data has ended up in your csv file? Grep may indeed find a match and output the data up to the next newline. Binary data might mess with the terminal output. Try piping the results into hexdump or xxd.

Comment: We can't see the output so we can't really say what's going on. Is your `grep` command an alias? Check with `type -a grep`.

Comment: If grep does not show a line number in the terminal, probable cause is embedded CR (\r) in a field. Send output from grep to a file and view in vi to see what is there. Use sed to extract a line range to see more context.

Comment: Along the lines suggested by @Hermann can you partition the file into a smaller subset e.g. binary chop to isolate the rogue row(s) then you can examine the manageable result with "od -ch" or somesuch

Comment: Try piping output via tr `grep -n 7CEC119CA8D46F42DC3DB4A971357E7D large_csv.txt | tr -d '\r'` which will remove carriage return (causes cursor to go back to beginning of line in terminal and further content is probably overwriting line number and other things).

Comment: `$ type -a grep` > `grep is aliased to 'grep --color=auto'` > `grep is /bin/grep`

Comment: it was an embedded carriage return (CR `\r`)  that was causing the problem.  @Paul_Pedant,  or @DevilaN  please put that as an answer and I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: I find `od -c` useful to look for control codes in text.